# How to find the eprocess structure in the RAM dump?

Tags: windows, api, ram, dump, computer-forensics

I'm new to this business and I have a difficult task. I need to write a program with which it would be possible to get the data of a certain process. This process is in a file .dmp, which is a full RAM dump. As far as I know, every process in Windows OS has an EPROCESS structure. So, having received this structure, I will be able to find the data of this process. Are there any libraries or functions that can facilitate this task? For example, in C++ or Python?

Comment: Using C++/Python does not make sense, use a debugger to view the info in the minidump.  Windbg is the standard choice, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234733/process-information-in-dump).

Comment: @HansPassant yes, I used windbg when researching the EPROCESS structure. But the problem is that I need to write the program myself